# Innosetup - Identify admin user and dll registration for standard users

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

During my innosetup application installation, I am registering a dll (which is used for windows right click context menu and icon overlays, something similar to dropbox/tortoise cvs) and performing some other stuffs also. Till now, I am insalling the application only for the administrator user. The dll will write the information in HKCR, HKLM. Now, I plan to support installation for other non-admin users too (standard user).

I tried several things like below,

- changed the privilegerequired from Admin to none.
- changed all registry updates from HKLM to HKCU.

But, if I try to install the application, the dll registration failed due to unable to write on HKCR. So, I planned to register dll only for the admin user. And for other normal users, plan to skip the dll registration and do the other stuff. But I can't find out, how to identify the current users is a admin user. Can any one let me know the following things,

- can we identify whether the current login user is a admin/power user or not?
- can we register dll (writing HKCR) with out admin rights?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether the current user is admin or power user:

```
[Code]
function IsRegularUser(): Boolean;
begin
    Result := not (IsAdminLoggedOn or IsPowerUserLoggedOn);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. any idea on registering context menu dlls in standard user.??

Comment: Note that this is only of use if you use `PrivilegesRequired=none` -- for every other value there's no point as you are guaranteed to either have an admin or a not-admin.  (Also, "power user" is an outdated concept that is deprecated in XP and doesn't exist in future versions.)  While it's possible to write a `none` install that can adapt to the type, it's usually not worth the hassle of duplicating logic and dual testing.  Just pick `admin` or `lowest` and stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing things to HKLM, then you are already installing for all users, not just the administrator user.  So you shouldn't change that.

The correct thing to do in an installer is to never write to HKCU.  (For best results, *also* never write to HKCR -- write to HKLM\Software\Classes instead.)

Comment: If the installer runs as administrator, how does the Setup know HKCU of which user to use? I get a warning that my installer may not have the expected behavior

Comment: It doesn't -- that's why the advice is to not do it.  HKCU is for the app itself, not the installer.